# Two problems in Batch: ELSE isn't Recognized as a Command, and ( was Unexpected at this Time

Tags: batch-file

In batch, with a Computer Power Level Checking Program, I tested and figured out that the "**(**" it's getting an error on is:

```
IF /I "%Battery.PowerOnline%"=="TRUE" (
```

I think the ELSE is:

```
    pause
    )
    ELSE
    (
    ECHO.
```

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
set x=1
:f
:: Use WMI to retrieve battery status information
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryStatus              Get Charging^,Critical^,Discharging /Format:list ^| FIND "=TRUE"') DO ECHO Battery is %%A
FOR /F "tokens=*  delims="  %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryStatus              Get PowerOnline^,RemainingCapacity  /Format:list ^| FIND "="')     DO SET  Battery.%%A
FOR /F "tokens=*  delims="  %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryRuntime             Get EstimatedRuntime                /Format:list ^| FIND "="')     DO SET  Battery.%%A
FOR /F "tokens=*  delims="  %%A IN ('WMIC /NameSpace:"\\root\WMI" Path BatteryFullChargedCapacity Get FullChargedCapacity             /Format:list ^| FIND "="')     DO SET  Battery.%%A

:: Calculate runtime left and capacity
SET /A Battery.EstimatedRuntime  = ( %Battery.EstimatedRuntime% + 30 ) / 60
SET /A Battery.RemainingCapacity = ( %Battery.RemainingCapacity%00 + %Battery.FullChargedCapacity% / 2 ) / %Battery.FullChargedCapacity%
echo %Battery.RemainingCapacity%%%
:: Display results
echo.
echo.
IF /I "%Battery.PowerOnline%"=="TRUE" (

    ECHO    Now working on main power
    ECHO. 
    ECHO    Battery %Battery.RemainingCapacity%%% charged
    ECHO. 
    ECHO. 
    pause
    )
    ELSE
    (
    ECHO. 
    ECHO    Estimated remaining runtime %Battery.EstimatedRuntime% minutes
    ECHO. 
    ECHO    Remaining capacity %Battery.RemainingCapacity%%%
    ECHO. 
    ECHO. 
    if "Battery.RemainingCapacity%"=="4555%" (
        pause
        echo       m
    ) else (
        goto f
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The

```
)
else
(
```

**MUST** be coded as

```
) else (
```

(ie. close-paren, `else` and re-open-paren all on the same line.)

Same comment for a `DO (` btw...

Comment: Hmmmmm, this gets rid of the else problem, but not the ( one.  Thanks for this, though.

Comment: Hmmmmm, perhaps `if "%Battery.RemainingCapacity%"=="4555" (` would work better than `if "Battery.RemainingCapacity%"=="4555%" (` . `if %Battery.RemainingCapacity% leq 4555 (` moreso,